# How to get rid of horizontal white lines appear out of nowhere in ggplot barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

[image]

I'm using ggplot and I get those weird horizontal lines out of geom_bar. I cannot provide a minimal working example: the same code works with few observations and it relies on data I am importing and transforming. However, I can show the relevant line of codes and cross my fingers someone ran into this issue:

```
ggplot(data) + geom_bar(aes(x=Horizon, y=Importance, fill=Groups),
                           position='fill', stat='identity') +
theme_timeseries2() +
scale_fill_manual(values=c('#1B9E77', 'orange2', 'black', 
                           'red2', 'blue4')) +
xlab('') + ylab('')
```

My personal function, `theme_timeseries2()` isn't the source of the problem: it happens even if I stop after geom_bar. I checked for missing values in `Importance` and every other column of my data frame and there are none.

It's also very odd: the white lines aren't the same on the zoomed page as in the plot window of RStudio. They do print in .png format when I save the file, so there really is something going on with those horizontal bars. Any theory about why `geom_bar()` does this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing the lines are due to a plotting bug between observations that go into each bar. I expect it'd go away if you first summarized, e.g. `library(dplyr); data %>% count(Horizon, Groups, wt = Importance, name = "Importance") %>% ggplot() + geom_col(aes(x = Horizon, y= Importance, fill = Groups), position = "fill") + ....`

Comment: And it worked! You can supply this as an answer so I can select it. I suspect this kind of nonsense can happen from time to time and people might enjoy this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the lines are due to a plotting bug between observations that go into each bar. (That could be related to the OS, the graphics device, and/or how ggplot2 interacts with them...)

I expect it'd go away if you summarized before ggplot2, e.g.:

```
library(dplyr); 
data %>% 
  count(Horizon, Groups, wt = Importance, name = "Importance") %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_col(aes(x = Horizon, y= Importance, fill = Groups), position = "fill") + ....
```

Answer (score 5):

You can fix it by adding the *fill* as *color*. Like this:

```
geom_bar(aes(x=Horizon, y=Importance, fill=Groups, color=Groups),
                       position='fill', stat='identity')
```

This was suggested [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/lines-on-bars-in-graph-when-publishing-shiny/46580/3).

Comment: Unfortunately, horizontals bars are still visible if you set a alpha inferior to 1.
Moreover, it produces 2 different legends for the fill and color parameters

Answer (score -1):

Mine went away when changing the size of the graphs in rmarkdown.