# ggplot - gaps in stacked bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have some data with transcript categories and counts and am trying to create a stacked bar plot with ggplot filled by category. Previous/example plots show a solid red block but when I tried with my data, I see lots of white lines. I thought they might be due to many the zero counts but after trying a few things including changing them to NA and excluding those rows altogether, the plot still has these white lines. Looking for some clarification, thanks!

Data subset (rows with zero counts removed):

```
isoform chrom strand length exons structural_category associated_transcript count
ENST00000627502.2     3      +    874     4   full-splice_match     ENST00000627502.2     2
ENST00000650569.1     1      -   6202    26   full-splice_match     ENST00000650569.1    51
ENST00000535093.1    18      +    582     6   full-splice_match     ENST00000535093.1    15
ENST00000338863.11     6      -   2983    13   full-splice_match    ENST00000338863.11     7
ENST00000570899.1    17      -    649     4   full-splice_match     ENST00000570899.1    24
ENST00000625998.2    13      -   5102    12   full-splice_match     ENST00000625998.2     7
ENST00000583693.5    17      +   3976     2   full-splice_match     ENST00000583693.5     9
ENST00000012134.7     6      -   9755     9   full-splice_match     ENST00000012134.7     4
ENST00000403263.5     2      -  14136    11   full-splice_match     ENST00000403263.5     1
ENST00000627368.2     5      -   1774    15   full-splice_match     ENST00000627368.2    14
```

[image: Stacked bar plot]

```
plot_isoformCount <- ggplot(isoClass_bambu, aes(x=method, y=count, fill=structural_category)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE), stat = "identity") +
  labs(y = "Read count", x = "Method", fill = "Structural category") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20), legend.position = "bottom") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = col.category) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = unit_format(unit = "M", scale = 1e-6))
# dev.off()

leg <- get_legend(plot_isoformCount)

plot_grid(plot_isoformClass, plot_isoformCount + theme(legend.position = "none"), leg, rel_heights = c(1, 0.2))
```

Comment: Can you add the code you used to make the histogram? And to export the figure?

Comment: Added! the figure is a screenshot

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66448947/how-to-get-rid-of-horizontal-white-lines-appear-out-of-nowhere-in-ggplot-barplot#comment117473839_66448947

Comment: @JonSpring yes, thank you! what led you to suggest/discover such a solution?